# CUBA platform postgresql connection timed out

Tags: java, database, postgresql, cuba-platform

I'm trying to connect my cuba platform application in to a postgresql db. earlier it worked fine. but now it is throwing an exception that connection is timed out I make all the configurations right same as before but it is not working.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out.
at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:368)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:279)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at com.haulmont.studio.backend.e.c.e.c(SourceFile:319)
at com.haulmont.studio.backend.e.c.e.e(SourceFile:261)
at com.haulmont.studio.backend.e.y.j(SourceFile:462)
at com.haulmont.studio.backend.e.y.a(SourceFile:153)
at com.haulmont.studio.backend.e.y.a(SourceFile:131)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at com.haulmont.studio.backend.h.run(SourceFile:62)
```

postgresql configuration

```
Database URL jdbc:postgresql://********.ciutcoh1pkgg.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/********
Database user *******
Database password *********
```

Both the username and password are correct.

Comment: Is port 5432 open?

Comment: yes it is open and my other applications are working fine with this db

Comment: Just to double-check: switch logging to DEBUG in Studio server window and press "Test connection" on Project Properties page. Then look at the log file at ~/haulmont/studio/logs/studio.log